# GitHub : API name/identity inside webhook payload?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, webhooks

I'm writing a Github API client and a webhook.

Is there any way to distinguish if an event (i.e assignment, issue open, etc etc) is trigered by API or by user directly (i.e via git's web ui) ?

I read what payload github will send on it's webhook call, but could not find one.

sincerely
-bino-

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it looks on the server side, but at least when using the UI, the POST payload seems to be form-data, and with API it is JSON-formatted.

From my tests with UI:

```
...
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="issue[user_assignee_ids][]"

28
------
```

and from GitHub API documentation:

```
{
  "assignees": [
    "hubot",
    "other_user"
  ]
}
```

This also means that the requests `content-type` header is different: for form data it is `content-type: multipart/form-data; ...` and for JSON it should be `content-type: application/json`.

Comment: actualy, it's always came to my script as `application/json`

Comment: as you wish. But Actualy your answer make me re-check my script, and it mean useful.